# Qt Vista Arbol con Checboxes

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, vistas, dependencias

He modificado el ejemplo de la página web de Qt: [EditableTreeModel Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html)
para que en la vista árbol me salgan CheckBoxes al lado de cada Item.

Pero...**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dependan unos de otros?** Es decir, que si el ChechBox del padre esta seleccionado automáticamente se haga Check en todas las de sus hijos. Y que si luego alguno de esos hijos se hace Uncheck el padre se ponga como parcialmente checkeado.

Aquí las funciones que he modificado para hacer que salgan las CheckBoxes.

En `TreeModel` la función `data`:

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()){
        return QVariant();
    }
    TreeItem *item1 = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    if ( role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == 0 )
    {
        return static_cast< int >( item1->isChecked() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked );
    }
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole)
        return QVariant();

    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);

    return item->data(index.column());
}
```

En `TreeModel`la función `flags`:

```
Qt::ItemFlags TreeModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return 0;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable | QAbstractItemModel::flags(index)|Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
}
```

En `TreeModel`la función `setData`:

```
bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
    if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Ischecked"<<item->isChecked();

        if(item->isChecked())
            item->setChecked(false);
        else
            item->setChecked(true);
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }

    if (role != Qt::EditRole)
        return false;
    bool result = item->setData(index.column(), value);


    if (result)
        emit dataChanged(index, index);

    return result;
}
```

En `TreeItem`he añadido nueva la función `setChecked`:

```
void TreeItem::setChecked(bool set)
{
    checked=set;
}
```

En `TreeItem`he añadido nueva la función `isChecked`:

```
bool TreeItem::isChecked()
{
    return checked;
}
```

Siendo `checked`una variable tipo `bool`dentro de mi clase `TreeItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que propagar el evento a mano. Para ello podrías hacer llamadas recursivas a `setData`, pero el resultado puede ser excesivamente lento ya que, entre otras cosas, implica lanzar el evento `dataChanged` una vez por cada fila modificada.

Otra opción sería crear una función que propagase el cambio y que, a la vez, agrupase la emisión de la señal:

```
void TreeModel::PropagateCheckedValue(QModelIndex const& parentIndex, TreeItem const& parent, bool value)
{
  for( int i=0; i<parent.childCount(); i++ )
  {
    TreeItem* child = parent.child(i);

    QModelIndex modelIndex = index(0,0,parentIndex);
    child->setChecked(value);
    PropagateCheckedValue(modelIndex,*child,value);
  }

  if( parent.childCount() > 0 )
  {
    QModelIndex begin = index(0,0,parentIndex);
    QModelIndex end = index(parent.childCount()-1,0,parentIndex);
    emit dataChanged(begin,end);
  }
}

bool TreeModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
    if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        bool checked = (static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(value.toInt()) == Qt::Checked);
        item->setChecked(checked);
        PropagateCheckedValue(index,*item,checked);

        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
```

Por cierto, nota que ahora el valor de *checked*  se recupera de `value` en vez de limitarme a invertir el estado de `checked`. Esto se hace así porque `setData` es una función pública que puede ser invocada desde cualquier sitio.

Se podría, por ejemplo, dar el caso de una llamada a `setData` para activar un check que ya se encuentra activo, lo que en tu caso provocaría que el check se desactivase.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me resulta muy útil. Pero no entiendo bien lo que explicas de recuperar el valor de Checked con `value`.

Comment: @MAP cuando tu cambias el check en la vista, la misma llama a `setData`, pasando por `value` el estado del check. Asumir que **siempre** que se llame a `setData` se va a cambiar el valor de *checked* es muy arriesgado. No te cuesta nada leer el valor de `value` que para eso lo recibes

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias :)